# NSSplitView issues with 10.7 and 10.8

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssplitview

i'm experiencing some issues with AutoLayout. Building for 10.8 with Xcode 4.6.2 none of the constraints i setup work for OSX 10.7. Are there any known issues around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262080/nssplitview-and-autolayout

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem too, so I wrote a custom split view based on constraints. See my repo for code. https://github.com/silvansky/TwinPanelView

Answer (score 1):

I personally gave up trying to use auto layout with split views. The manual layout works the best, in my experience, and is actually not much more complicated at all.

In particular, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/843870/2308693

It's brilliant, and it gives you full control of everything (so I agree fully with the first comment on that answer).